# Explicit equations of an image and its normality

Tags: algebraic-geometry

One has a mapping $\phi:\mathbb{A}^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{A}^4$ given by $\phi(x,y)=(x,xy,y(y-1),y^2(y-1))$. First, I am trying to find explicit equations defining $\mathrm{Im}(\phi)$. It is easy to check that the zero locus $Z=Zeros(t_2\cdot t_3-t_1\cdot t_4,t_3^3-t_4^2+t_3\cdot t_4)\subset \mathbb{A}^4$ contains the $\phi$-image. It seems to be obvious that the image of $\phi$ is of dimension $2$ (because of the dimension of $\mathbb{A}^2$). Does that mean that there are no more equations? It is easy to see however that $\phi(\mathbb{A}^2)\ne Z$ (e.g., $(0,1,0,0)\in Z\setminus \mathrm{Im}(\phi)$). Did I miss any of equations?!

Also is there any trick to show that the $\phi$-image is not normal?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate equations defining $\overline{\phi(\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{Q})} \subseteq \mathbb{A}^4_\mathbb{Q}$ with Macaulay 2. I appended the computation at the end of this answer. The principle of this computation is the following:

To compute $\ker f$ for $f:k[x_1,\ldots,x_n] \to k[y_1,\ldots,y_m]$ with $f(x_i) \mapsto g_i(y_1,\ldots,y_m)$ one goes into the bigger ring $A=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_m]$ and considers in $A$ the ideal $I$ generated by $(x_i - g_i(y_1,\ldots,y_m))_{i=1,\ldots,n}$. Then one computes a groebner base $h_1,\ldots,h_s \in A$ of $I$ with respect to a term order, where any monomial containing a $y_j$ is bigger than a monomial that contains only $x_i$. One could take a so called *lexicographic term order*, but it is more efficient to use an *elimination term order*.

These concepts are explained exactly in any book on groebner base applications in algebraic geometry, for example in the book of Cox, Little, O'Shea ( I found it online here: http://www.math.ku.dk/~holm/download/ideals-varieties-and-algorithms.pdf).

Finally one takes from the $h_1,\ldots,h_s$ only the $h_{i_1},\ldots,h_{i_r}$ which contain only monomials consisting of $x_i$'s alone, that is $h_{i_\nu} \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n] \subseteq A$.

These form a groebner base of $\ker f$. The proof of this fact is not difficult and you can look it up in the abovementioned book.

Regarding the normality of $Z = \overline{\phi(\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{Q})}$, it seems by the calculation of 'integralClosure' that I appended at the end, that $Z$ is indeed not normal, as a new variable w_0,0 is introduced in the result. Note also, that it is necessary to check if $\phi(\mathbb{A}^2_\mathbb{Q})$ is already a closed set in $\mathbb{A}^4_\mathbb{Q}$.

If you want to play with Macaulay 2 yourself, on the homepage [Macaulay2](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/), there is a link leading to an online version, where you can use the system in an online session in the browser.

```
+ M2 --no-readline --print-width 79
Macaulay2, version 1.6.0.1
with packages: ConwayPolynomials, Elimination, IntegralClosure, LLLBases,
               PrimaryDecomposition, ReesAlgebra, TangentCone

i1 : R=QQ[t_1..t_4]

o1 = R

o1 : PolynomialRing

i2 : S=QQ[x,y]

o2 = S

o2 : PolynomialRing

i3 : phi=map(S,R,{x,x*y,y*(y-1),y^2*(y-1)})

                       2       3    2
o3 = map(S,R,{x, x*y, y  - y, y  - y })

o3 : RingMap S <--- R

i4 : ker phi

                          3           2     2                 2             2 
o4 = ideal (t t  - t t , t  + t t  - t , t t  + t t  - t t , t t  + t t  - t ,
             2 3    1 4   3    3 4    4   1 3    1 4    2 4   1 3    1 2    2 
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------
      3        2    3
     t t  + t t  - t )
      1 4    1 2    2

o4 : Ideal of R

i5 : gens gb oo

o5 = | t_2t_3-t_1t_4 t_3^3+t_3t_4-t_4^2 t_1t_3^2+t_1t_4-t_2t_4
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     t_1^2t_3+t_1t_2-t_2^2 t_1^3t_4+t_1t_2^2-t_2^3 |

             1       5
o5 : Matrix R  <--- R

i6 : ideal oo

                          3           2     2                 2             2 
o6 = ideal (t t  - t t , t  + t t  - t , t t  + t t  - t t , t t  + t t  - t ,
             2 3    1 4   3    3 4    4   1 3    1 4    2 4   1 3    1 2    2 
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------
      3        2    3
     t t  + t t  - t )
      1 4    1 2    2

o6 : Ideal of R

i9 : i1=ker phi

                          3           2     2                 2             2 
o9 = ideal (t t  - t t , t  + t t  - t , t t  + t t  - t t , t t  + t t  - t ,
             2 3    1 4   3    3 4    4   1 3    1 4    2 4   1 3    1 2    2 
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------
      3        2    3
     t t  + t t  - t )
      1 4    1 2    2

o9 : Ideal of R

i10 : R1=R/i1

o10 = R1

o10 : QuotientRing

i11 : integralClosure R1

                                          QQ[w   , t , t , t , t ]
                                              0,0   1   2   3   4
o11 = -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                              2                                                      2
      (t t  - t t , w   t  - t , w   t  + t  - t , w   t  - t t , w   t  + t  - t , w    + w    - t )
        2 3    1 4   0,0 4    3   0,0 3    3    4   0,0 2    1 3   0,0 1    1    2   0,0    0,0    3

o11 : QuotientRing
```